# Why fastlane upload to TestFlight fails behind proxy?

Tags: ios, testflight, fastlane

I am using fastlane to build the IPA file and trying to upload it to the test flight. I am working behind a proxy network, so exporting http_proxy and https_proxy is working fine.

You can also see from the below log, '**Login successful**'. But when fastlane is trying to upload the file, getting **Malformed reply from SOCKS server** error.

What do you think? How do you think I can fix this error?

```
[13:51:26]: [32m----------------------------------
[13:51:26]: [32m--- Step: upload_to_testflight ---
[13:51:26]: [32m----------------------------------
[13:51:26]: Login to App Store Connect (****)
[13:51:29]: Login successful
[13:51:30]: [32mReady to upload new build to TestFlight (App: 1****2)...
[13:51:30]: Going to upload updated app to App Store Connect
[13:51:30]: [32mThis might take a few minutes. Please don't interrupt the script.
[13:53:46]: [31m[Transporter Error Output]: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need to have outbound access to TCP port 443.
[13:53:46]: [31m[Transporter Error Output]: An exception has occurred: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
[13:55:48]: [31m[Transporter Error Output]: Communication error. Please use diagnostic mode to check connectivity. You need to have outbound access to TCP port 443.
[13:55:48]: [31m[Transporter Error Output]: An exception has occurred: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
```

Comment: Error message says "You need to have outbound access to TCP port 443.". Do you have that?

Comment: Also, did you have a look at https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/pilot/#firewall-issues?

Comment: @janpio sorry for the delayed answer. I have tried adding **DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS="-t DAV"** environmental variable but that did not work.